# how to make preg_match with back symbols

Tags: php

in code

```
<td><span class="user "><i class="arrived" title="Провинциалист"></i><a href="/player/154646/">-Ваня-</a><span class="level">[5]</span></span></td>
<td class="value"></td>
<td><span class="user "><i class="arrived" title="Провинциалист"></i><a href="/player/174078/">asen</a><span class="level">[6]</span></span></td>
<td class="value"></td>
<td><span class="user "><i class="arrived" title="Провинциалист"></i><a href="/player/198745/">jsan</a><span class="level">[7]</span></span></td>
<td class="value"></td>
<td><span class="user "><i class="arrived" title="Провинциалист"></i><a href="/player/1698735/">aseto</a><span class="level">[8]</span></span></td>
<td class="value"></td>`
```

How can I do and 1-st to do `preg_match` on "level">[" and if the number is >= of 6 and <8 then to do preg_match on the same line before this number for example 1st `preg_match` level">[6] and sees that it is equal to and then make `preg_match` on player/ and sees that number is "174078"

Comment: load in domdocument and use xpath - `//span[@class="level"][number((translate(.,"][",""))) >= 6 and number((translate(.,"][",""))) < 8]/../a/@href`

Answer (score 0):

For the given HTML you could use something like

```
/<a.*href="(.*?)".*"level">\[[67]\]/
```

but that is really ugly. I would prefer using XPath to grep HTML elements: http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php